# Prevent the automatic URL linking added in last update

Tags: posts, links

Since one of the recent WP updates, all URLs in my [post contents](https://www.andreszsogon.com/cordova-bluetooth-printer-plugin-demo-app/) are now magically converted to **clickable links** using some obscure Javascript function on page load, and I can't find a way to disable this. Even text inside **blockquotes** and **code** tags is linked, which is very inconvenient. In the case of code blocks it even uses a different font size to make it worse.

Is there some setting or function to prevent this? I don't want to revert to a previous version. Thank you.

*Sample of linked URL inside blockquote:*

[image]

Comment: It doesn't do that for me. Any chance this is a browser plugin you've got, not something on the site? Can you try a different browser or a different PC?

Comment: Chrome did the same, now suddenly both browsers stopped linking the links without me touching anything. Maybe the Disqus plugin was messing with the content, this plugin seems to be quite aggresive with its JS functions.